# Uncaught TypeError: onCheckedClicked is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I get this error message when I try to call onclick with conditional rendering. I have one functional component for a Task and based on the status, one of the functions should fire.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9lOh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the function, `isPending()` instead of `isPending` on your div.